# Real time application (React + Django)

Tags: reactjs, django, websocket, real-time, django-channels

Just want to get some suggestion on what would be best approach to create a real time application.
What architecture and libraries should be used on both sides

I have looked int to sockit.io for front end and channels for the  django side, Do I have to use both of them or only one side front-end or back-end

Comment: You can use graphql with Channels and [strawberry](https://strawberry.rocks/) with react-relay on UI side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Channels in back-end side to handle websocket or something like that. Then your font-end side can realtime communicate with backend through it